# Running a command without using exec() but changing user with php

Tags: php, linux, permissions, sudo

What I'm trying to do is write a scrip that allows someone to sign  up and when they do enter their pgp public key.  That seems easy enough.

Here's what I'm stuck on.

I have my keyring setup under a system user so when I want to add a key I have to do:

```
sudo -u encryption /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /var/gpg/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keys.keyserver.org --search myemail@DOMAIN.COM  ( or --import key.asc )
```

( encryption being a system user )

So when the user signs up I need their key to go to the right spot which means I have to sudo, which from what I see means I have to do an exec().

So I could:

```
$command = "insert command string to be executed here";
$oldhome = getEnv("HOME");
putenv("HOME=/var/gpg/.gnupg");
$result = exec($command, $output, $errorcode);
putenv("HOME=$oldhome");
```

I'm guessing the use of exec() is frowned upon, not to mention having to sudo to another user. Plus that just doesn't seem right to me.

Also from what I've read the sudo portion has to be done with passwordless sudo.

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Also comment out the following line (in /etc/sudoers via visudo), if it is there:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Is there a better, safer way to go about this?  I guess I could move the keyring to say www-data but I'm not sure what the implications are of that.  The keyring is in use by the mailserver to encrypt mail so it can really be moved anywhere.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

UPDATE:

I very well may be wrong here but here is how I "solved this"

```
www-data ALL=(encryption) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/gpg
```

That is what went in my sudoers file.  That really only allows it to run just that command unless I'm mistaken in my reading, if so please let me know.

That way I can run exec() and now the only real thing I have to worry about is verifying the data.

Comment: I would write a separate "server" process that does whatever you need done as a privileged user. Send commands to that "server" process using whatever form of inter-process communication you like best. (Files, sockets, pipes, whatever.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So pipe out to a bash script for example, or even another non world visible php script?

Comment: Not quite. Have the other script already running, so you just need to tell it what to do.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks david. Off to do some research.  Can't say I've ever had to do this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was thinking about this and wondered if I even have to bother to go the way @DavidSchwartz suggested. I'm not trying to run with elevated permissions, if anything I"m trying to run with limited permissions. I really only need to be able to run a single command.  Can exec() be made safe enough to use in this instance? It will have input passed to it, ie a pgp key.  I don't know if I can clean the input enough to not have to worry about it or do I have to look more to user permissions to only allow the running of a single command, in the case gpg.